# Set class on label attribute of Symfony3 checkbox

Tags: symfony, checkbox, twig

I have a symfony3 project where I'm adding a custom class to some form fields via twig. This is all working fine **except** for the checkbox label. My custom class does not show in the label for the checkbox as expected.

EDIT: adding my form builder:

```
class ReferralFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('modality', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Modality::class,
                'placeholder' => 'Choose modality',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
            ])
            ->add('referralFromDoctor', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Doctor::class,
                'placeholder' => 'Choose a doctor:',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
            ])
            ->add('isFollowup', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label' => 'Follow up visit?',
            ])
            ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Referral::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here's my twig template:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

<div id="js-order-wrapper">
    {{ form_label(form.modality, 'Type', { 'label_attr': {'class': 'js-hidden-row'} }) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.modality, { 'attr': {'class': 'js-hidden-row'} }) }}

    {{ form_label(form.referralFromDoctor, 'Ordering clinician', { 'label_attr': {'class': 'js-hidden-row'} }) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.referralFromDoctor, { 'attr': {'class': 'js-hidden-row'} }) }}

    {{ form_label(form.isFollowup, 'Follow up?', { 'label_attr': {'class': 'js-hidden-row'} }) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.isFollowup, { 'attr': {'class': 'js-hidden-row'} }) }}
</div>

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

and here is the rendered html:

```
<div id="js-order-wrapper">
    <label class="js-hidden-row control-label required" for="referral_form_modality">Type</label>
    <select id="referral_form_modality" name="referral_form[modality]" required="required" class="js-hidden-row form-control"><option value="">Choose modality</option></select>

    <label class="js-hidden-row control-label required" for="referral_form_referralFromDoctor">Ordering clinician</label>
    <select id="referral_form_referralFromDoctor" name="referral_form[referralFromDoctor]" required="required" class="js-hidden-row form-control"><option value="">Choose a doc</option></select

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="required">
            <input type="checkbox" id="referral_form_isFollowup" name="referral_form[isFollowup]" required="required" class="js-hidden-row" value="1" /> Follow up visit?
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the class 'js-hidden-row' is correctly applied to the labels for the  fields, but for the checkbox the class is not applied to the label. Seems like a bug to me.

Short of writing a custom block of code to render the checkbox, is there a better solution?

Comment: Can you show all Twig template?

Comment: Can you please show the full twig template and your overwritten form theming (if any)? Your twig example states "Follow up?" whereas your rendered HTML is not the same ("Follow up visit?"). Anyway, Symfony can't render ``label > input::checkbox`` this way, without any customization.
It may help a lot, if you show us your full code.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have no form theming in my template. My full template is very long and I've just extracted the relevant parts in my question above. The difference in labels comes from my form builder, which I've added to my question for completeness. My goal is to simply hide/show the checkbox (and its label) via jQuery. I see no way to do that since even the surrounding <div> element does not have a unique (or changeable) class or id.